# Python Beautiful Soup: Get links that belong to a "div class"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know how to get links like this:

```
 tags = soup.find_all("a", href = True)
```

But what do I need to do if I only want to the links that belong to a specific "div class". For instance in the html code you could see "div class = "information" in the level above the "a href".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` to get your desired div.

**Ex:**

```
div = soup.find("div", class_="information")
for tag in div.find_all("a", href = True):
    #....
```

Comment: Unfortunately that solution also contains all of the sub-classes that is within "a href". I just want it to print out the link. There is btw also a class name, but "for tag in div.find_all("a", href = True,class_  ="a-reset")" does not work. That solution prints out value that is not the link (the opposite).

Comment: `for tag in div.find_all("a", href = True, {"class": "a-reset"})` ?